# How does one create a keyword symbol from a string?

Tags: common-lisp

Making a symbol from a string is quite simple:

```
(intern "test") => test
```

I'm struggling to create *keyword* symbols for a plist. Looking for something like:

```
(XXXX "test") => :test
```

Note that `(intern ":test")` does not produce a *keyword* symbol but rather a symbol containing a colon (e.g. `|:test|`).

How can one correctly generate keyword symbols in Common Lisp? Thanks!

Comment: Note that you don't have to use keywords as indicators in a plist.  [`getf`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_getf.htm) works with any object as an indicator.  Thus you can `(getf '(1 one 2 two) 2) => two` or `(getf '(a b c d) 'a) => b)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keywords are normal symbols except that they live inside the KEYWORD package:

```lisp
? (defvar x (intern "NEWKW" "KEYWORD"))
X
? x
:NEWKW
? (keywordp x)
T
```

See also [here](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw61/CLHS/Body/f_intern.htm).

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Interestingly, on my implementation (Allegro CL) the package was lowercase (i.e. "keyword" instead of "KEYWORD").

Comment: @ElliotPenson Are you running in "modern mode"?

Comment: @ElliotPenson That's non standard behavior, and if you're not running in "modern mode", you could report that as a bug.  The name of the standard package is `"KEYWORD"`.  See [11.1.2 Standardized Packages](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/11_ab.htm) in the HyperSpec.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Yes, turns out that my "Current reader case mode" is :case-sensitive-lower.